# JSON Response failing - No message available Error

Tags: jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

I am running json request  on jmeter and its failing with the below error. I have added the 'Header Manager with Content-Type:  application/json;charset=UTF-8' . Could you please guide if i am missing.

Response:status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"No message available","path":"/abc"

Sample Result:

Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 500
Response message:

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 500 
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 13 Nov 2018 14:41:23 GMT
Set-Cookie: 92ed481f1aaad95790b815a41735930c=fb7ef40c51ff9a9645b30e489e56c7e4; path=/; HttpOnly

HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: application/json;charset=UTF-8
DataEncoding: UTF-8

Comment: 500 means that the server had some error/s while processing the request. Rather take a look at your server logs and look for errors / exceptions in there.

Comment: The same endpoint and request works fine via Swagger and Postman

Answer (score 0):

Was able to resolve the issue. Need include an additional header
'Accept:application/hal+json' along with Content-type: application/json

Thanks.